Is it possible to have the SummerNote toolbar seperate?
if I have two or more SummerNote editable areas on a page? I want multiple small editable blocks so allocating the full toolbar to each isn't going to work with the layout.
Is it possible to have a single toolbar fixed somewhere on the page that controls the currently selectable editable area (ideally getting disabled if none is selected)
Air mode would almost solve the requirement if the popover could be made to appear clicking into a defined area and disappear on exit.
Have tried looking through the 'deep dive' and code but can't find anything that seems to solve this use-case.
